# active X Irmage irimage loadimage

Tags: delphi, ole

active X Irmage object that has a loading funcion but i dont now how to put it to work

```
function TIRimage.LoadImage(ImageHandle: OLE_HANDLE; ImageType: Smallint; 
  BigEndian: WordBool): WordBool;
begin
  Result := DefaultInterface.LoadImage(ImageHandle, ImageType, BigEndian);
end;
```

Botão 
IRimage1.LoadImage[ 'c:\IR_1093.jpg' ] ;

Comment: It helps telling us about your TIRimage, what is it?

Comment: It´s active X like timage that load´s IRimages (images with radiometric values).